# How can I use Photoshops Match Color function through javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I'm wondering if there is syntax to use Match Color, I've looked through the Adobe Photoshop CS3 JavaScript Reference [here](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs3_javascript_ref.pdf) , and didn't find anything on it.

I'm working on color balancing a lot of imagery, and being able to select a target image through "Match Color" is a great functionality. And being able to use a script would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with the ***ScriptingListener.plugin*** gives me something like:

```
// =======================================================
var idmatchColor = stringIDToTypeID( "matchColor" );
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idLght = charIDToTypeID( "Lght" );
    desc3.putInteger( idLght, 98 );
    var idClrR = charIDToTypeID( "ClrR" );
    desc3.putInteger( idClrR, 98 );
    var idFade = charIDToTypeID( "Fade" );
    desc3.putInteger( idFade, 8 );
    var idneutralizeColor = stringIDToTypeID( "neutralizeColor" );
    desc3.putBoolean( idneutralizeColor, true );
    var idfsel = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
    desc3.putBoolean( idfsel, true );
    var idSrce = charIDToTypeID( "Srce" );
        var ref1 = new ActionReference();
        var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
        var idBckg = charIDToTypeID( "Bckg" );
        ref1.putProperty( idLyr, idBckg );
        var idDcmn = charIDToTypeID( "Dcmn" );
        ref1.putName( idDcmn, "Test_Image.jpg" );
    desc3.putReference( idSrce, ref1 );
executeAction( idmatchColor, desc3, DialogModes.NO );
```

You can find the settable parameters from UI here translated into Photoshop Javascript, i.e. **Fade** is set to a value of **8** or the **Neutralize** checkbox is checked (**true**).

In the third last line you see the calculation source set to **Test_Image.jpg** here.

I think this gives you a good starting point to go on. I recommend to replace the values here (98, 98, 8 etc.) with variables and wrap it in a JS function.

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg